# Looking for an AngularJS carousel

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm looking for an AngularJS carousel module that can mimic exactly the visual format of this picture:

[image]

I tried using https://mihnsen.github.io/ui-carousel/ but got errors:
https://github.com/mihnsen/ui-carousel/issues/35

I just need something that works well in AngularJS and visually mimics the picture. Any suggestions?

Comment: I've found some templates at https://bootsnipp.com/tags/carousel?page=1 that I'm going to try:

https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/thumbnail-carousel

and

https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/simple-carousel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found this template and used it with success:
 bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/simple-carousel

I just had to make minor css adjustments and used `data-target="#Carousel"` instead of `href="#Carousel"` in the controls.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [this](https://codepen.io/Fabiano/pen/LACzk) one? It seems that he's using just bootstrap and some CSS to do it.

```
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.10.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js
```

It also shows the scope variables that he uses to get the carousel configured. It's not exactly the same, but it's the closer I found. If it's not what you want, you can do little CSS changes to look like the picture (:

Comment: Paula, could you point me to a link with an exemple, to see if that's what I need, please?